# Existence of uniformly continuous right inverse of bounded linear (surjective) maps between Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Is there a known description of pairs of Banach spaces $(E,F)$ such that each continuous linear map from $E$ onto $F$ has a uniformly continuous right inverse? In his famous paper in Fund Math (2008), Kalton shows that the quotient map from the space of bounded sequences onto its quotient by the closed subspace of null sequences does not have this property. Same question may be asked for Lipschitz right inverse.